# Google-Related Redirect Chain on Pingdom

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, pagespeed

I am trying to improve my website’s Pingdom score by removing a redirect chain linked to Google Analytics and DoubleClick. I have been doing research on this problem, but every similar one dealt with totally different chains (e.g. those with image and CSS files).

Since my chain has only two Google-related items, I am sure neither my website’s CSS, JavaScript, nor PHP files are causing it to happen.

[image: Redirect chain related to Google Analytics and DoubleClick]

Does anyone know if there is an .htaccess code or special other code for resolving this? I could not find one for a long time, and it would really help!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @Nathan No, and people kept ignoring this question no matter how many times I edited it.

Comment: May I ask... is this Magento?

Comment: @Nathan No, this is a single-page site consisting of one PHP file, one CSS file, and two JS files (navigation bar script and jQuery).

Comment: Turns out the issue is related to the analytics.js file used for Google analytics. Are you serving this file locally by chance?

Comment: @Nathan Nope, I pasted the analytics code as is.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm asking if your serving the analytics.js code from your server, or is it being called from Google's server? Here, try going here: https://www.webpagetest.org and see this: https://dr.tt/view?d=efbj03bq1a4dimk%2F2016-08-13%20at%206.47%20PM%20(1).png%2F

Comment: @Nathan Actually, yes I am hosting the script locally.

Comment: Me too. That's the problem me thinks. The script itself calls doubleclick (search the script yourself). I'm not sure yet how to resolve the issue, but this is at least the cause. Delete the script (or move it so your web server doesn't pick it up) and try pingdom again. I think you'll see the problem goes away.

Comment: Did follow the instructions in my answer Jon?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have Demographics- and interest reports activated for the web property in Google Analytics. Disable them both as well as "Advertising Reporting Features" under "Tracking info / Data collection". This will eliminate the redirect!

If you are using Pingdom make sure to give it some time until the changes are detected! If you run directly after making the change Pingdom might still detect a redirect (for whatever reason).

The above relates to the doubleclick script. As for the analytics-script you need to host the file locally to get rid of the Leverage Browser Caching penalty in pingdom:

https://community.keycdn.com/t/hosting-google-analytics-locally/437